# Does web socket need port forwarding?

Tags: http, websocket, portforwarding

I am trying to send a file from a client to another client by using web socket.
On the middle of two client there will be a web server to relay them.

First of all, is this kind of logic possible?
If it is possible, will the clients require any port forwarding?

I sent files through socket directly before I found that upnp is sometimes has no effect on some free wifi zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port Forwarding is only needed if one client wants to **directly** connect to the other client.  But if all of your websocket messages are being relayed through a public server, then Port Forwarding is not needed.

Comment: Is the relay possible? Since I only did work on sending requests and directly getting response with an Http server, this kind of solution is really new to me.

Comment: Relaying is possible if you write your own websocket server, yes. It would know all of the clients that are connected to it, and can forward messages from one client to another client as needed.